Kotlin Compose instrumented UI test: How to perform drag and drop on the screen?
I'm currently working on a composable screen that looks something like this:

Those tiles are draggable, you can reorder them by dragging it and moving it to another place. And this is what I want to test automatically :) I would like to drag the tile #2 under the tile #3.

I've already tried to achieve this by using performTouchInput, like this:
onNodeWithText("Tile 2")
                    .performTouchInput {
                        down(center)
                        advanceEventTime(viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis + 100)
                        updatePointerTo(0, center + Offset(0f, 200f))
                        move()
                        up()
                    }

but it looks like it just presses the tile for a moment, then releases it, and then swipes the screen down - which is obviously not what I intended.
I have already tried several different solutions, but none of them worked for me. I'm running out of ideas.
How to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

I have similar functionality, and I'm able to test it as follows:
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("PlanComposable: Work").performTouchInput {
        down(center)
        advanceEventTime(viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis + 100)
        moveBy(Offset(0f, y = 64.dp.toPx()), 0)
        advanceEventTime(1000)
        up()
    }

moveBy() calls updatePointerBy() and move() under the hood.
It was essential to include the advanceEventTime(1000) after the moveBy() call to give the UI time to reflect the drag.
I'm unsure if the drag is properly initiated. Performing gestures using onNodeWithText("Tile 2") will perform gestures on the text composable inside your tile composable. Interacting with the text composable should work, but one thing you can try is adding a Modifier.testTag("Tile $tileNumber") to your tile composable and using composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("Tile 2).performTouchInput... This way, "center" will be the center of the whole tile instead of the center of the text composable inside the tile.
I hope this helps.
